# Overleaf: Argument of \@@cite has an extra }. Runaway argument?

Tags: citing, overleaf, apacite

I have a problem with my document. When I compile the PDF Overleaf says that every citation in my document has the following error:

> Argument of @@cite has an extra }. Runaway argument?

Sometimes Overleaf also says

> Undefined control sequence.

The citations do work but in the PDF document they destroy the captions of the figures and the list of figures - in the list of figures the caption is not displayed but the page and some random number. The citations are made by Jabref. They are not manually created.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
% \usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\linespread{1.5} % Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{tabularx}   
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\lstset{language=c++,
    frame=top, frame=bottom,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    tabsize = 4,
    showstringspaces = false,
    keywordstyle =\color{dkblue},
    stringstyle = \color{red},
    commentstyle = \color{dkgreen}
}
\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = darkgray,
urlcolor = blue,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = blue] {hyperref}

\begin{document}
      \section{example}
       .....some example text\cite{deterding}.

    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{bachelor.bib}
\appendix
\end{document}

And here is the entry in the bib-file:
```

```
@Article{deterding,
  author = {Sebastian Deterding, Dan Dixon},
  title  = {{From Game Design Elements to Gamefulness: Defining Gamification}},
  year   = {2011},
}
```

I hope the example is somewhat helpful. Does anyone know what causes this internal error?

Comment: This is not related to Overleaf, `apacite` should be loaded after `hyperref` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180623/21344

Comment: `apacite` is one of the few weird packages that must be loaded **after** `hyperref`. If you move `\usepackage{apacite}` to after `\usepackage....{hyperref}` your test document builds fine.

Comment: Actually, comparing in more detail your preamble with the list provided in the question @PaulGessler linked to, you are loading quite a few packages that can benefit from being loaded after `hyperref`. These include also `tabularx`, `url`, and `glossaries`.